# Looping nested ArrayList to display values from JSON using gson

Tags: java, android, json, android-layout, gson

Q: I have json that have values in form of nested element, As you can see below i have values from server inside the array and than there is second array inside it. Now i using gson to parse this values, Every thing is working up-until  `"orderDetailList"` but when i try to loop throw "subItemPart" I'm unable to retrieve values of subItemPart object.

Source Code:

Input JSON String in file myFile.json  (Validated using JSONLint: Valid JSON)

```
{
  "customerId": "CUST01",
  "orderId": "101010",
  "orderTotal": 99.99,
  "orderDetailList": [
    {
      "lineId": "1",
      "itemNumber": "ABC",
      "quantity": 9,
      "price": 10.0,
      "subItemPart":[{"itemName":"RAM", "quantity": 5}, {"itemName":"LED", "quantity": 3}]
    },
    {
      "lineId": "2",
      "itemNumber": "XYZ",
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 9.99 ,
      "subItemPart":[{"itemName":"RAM", "quantity": 5}, {"itemName":"LED", "quantity": 3}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Java source code for converting a JSON String to Java Object

```
package com.as400samplecode;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.as400samplecode.util.OrderDetail;
import com.as400samplecode.util.OrderHeader;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class ParseJSON {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  String myJSONString = "";
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

  try {

   String sCurrentLine;

   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/myFile.json"));

   while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    myJSONString = myJSONString + sCurrentLine;
   }

  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   try {
    if (bufferedReader != null){
     bufferedReader.close();
    }
   } catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  OrderHeader orderHeader = gson.fromJson(myJSONString, OrderHeader.class);

  System.out.println("Order Information --->");
  System.out.println("Customer Id: " + orderHeader.getCustomerId());
  System.out.println("Order Id: " + orderHeader.getOrderId());
  System.out.println("Order Total: " + orderHeader.getOrderTotal());

  ArrayList<OrderDetail> orderDetailList = orderHeader.getOrderDetailList();
  for (int i=0; i<orderDetailList.size(); i++){
   System.out.println("Order Detail --->");
   OrderDetail orderDetail = orderDetailList.get(i);
   System.out.println("Line Id: " + orderDetail.getLineId());
   System.out.println("Item Number: " + orderDetail.getItemNumber());
   System.out.println("Quantity: " + orderDetail.getQuantity());
   System.out.println("Price: " + orderDetail.getPrice());

   **//HOW CAN I HERE LOOP AND DISPLAY VALUES OF SubOrderItem?**
   //I GET error when i do: System.out.println("SubItem: " +orderDetail.getSubOrderDetail.itemName);

  }

 }


}
```

Java source code for OrderHeader Object

```
package com.as400samplecode.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OrderHeader {

 String customerId = null;
 String orderId = null;
 Double orderTotal = null;
 ArrayList<OrderDetail> orderDetailList;

 public String getCustomerId() {
  return customerId;
 }
 public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
  this.customerId = customerId;
 }
 public String getOrderId() {
  return orderId;
 }
 public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
  this.orderId = orderId;
 }
 public Double getOrderTotal() {
  return orderTotal;
 }
 public void setOrderTotal(Double orderTotal) {
  this.orderTotal = orderTotal;
 }
 public ArrayList<OrderDetail> getOrderDetailList() {
  return orderDetailList;
 }
 public void setOrderDetailList(ArrayList<OrderDetail> orderDetailList) {
  this.orderDetailList = orderDetailList;
 }

}
```

Java source code for OrderDetail Object

```
package com.as400samplecode.util;

public class OrderDetail {

 String lineId = null;
 String itemNumber = null;
 int quantity = 0;
 Double price = null;
 ArrayList<SubOrderItemDetail> subItemPart;


 public String getLineId() {
  return lineId;
 }
 public void setLineId(String lineId) {
  this.lineId = lineId;
 }
 public String getItemNumber() {
  return itemNumber;
 }
 public void setItemNumber(String itemNumber) {
  this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
 }
 public int getQuantity() {
  return quantity;
 }
 public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
  this.quantity = quantity;
 }
 public Double getPrice() {
  return price;
 }
 public void setPrice(Double price) {
  this.price = price;
 }
 public ArrayList<SubItemDetail> getSubOrderDetail() {
  return subItemPart;
 }
 public void setSubOrderDetail(ArrayList<SubItemDetail> subItemPart) {
  this.subItemPart = subItemPart;
 }


}
```

**//My question is How do i get values of this element, Since they are values of json nested arrays**
Java source code for SubItemPart Object

```
package com.as400samplecode.util;

public class SubOrderDetail {

 String itemName = null;
 int quantity = 0;


 public String getLineId() {
  return itemName;
 }
 public void setLineId(String itemName) {
  this.itemName = itemName;
 }
 public int getItemNumber() {
  return quantity;
 }
 public void setItemNumber(int quantity) {
  this.quantity = quantity;
 }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all you have a little mess with your class names. Because in your class `OrderDetail` you have:

```
ArrayList<SubOrderItemDetail> subItemPart;

//...

public ArrayList<SubItemDetail> getSubOrderDetail() {
  return subItemPart;
}
public void setSubOrderDetail(ArrayList<SubItemDetail> subItemPart) {
  this.subItemPart = subItemPart;
}
```

And then your other class is:

```
public class SubOrderDetail {
```

So... do you realise you have 3 different names for the same class (i.e., `SubOrderItemDetail`, `SubItemDetail` and `SubOrderDetail`)?

---

That said, if you fix the problem with the names, your code is working, and you only have a very simple problem with displaying it. In order to display a sub-list inside a `for` you can just add this code where you have your commented lines:

```
ArrayList<SubOrderItemDetail> subOrderDetailList = orderDetail.getSubOrderDetail();
for (int j = 0; j < orderDetailList.size(); j++) {
  System.out.println("Sub Order Detail --->");
  SubOrderItemDetail subOrderDetail = subOrderDetailList.get(j);
  System.out.println("Line Id: " + subOrderDetail.getLineId());
  System.out.println("Item Number: " + subOrderDetail.getItemNumber());
}
```

Note that in the code I've written I'm following the style in your previous code, but I prefer this way:

```
for (SubOrderItemDetail soid : orderDetail.getSubOrderDetail()) {
  System.out.println("Line Id: " + soid.getLineId());
  System.out.println("Item Number: " + soid.getItemNumber());
}
```

You can also follow this style in your previous `for` and your code will be much cleaner...

Comment: Hey man, Thanks for help. It worked for me! You are awesome!You use twitter? if so add me: twitter.com/ideaDX Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In `OrderDetail` class instead of

```
  `ArrayList<SubOrderItemDetail> orderDetailList;`
```

should be

`ArrayList<SubOrderItemDetail> subItemPart;`

as same as in JSON.

And in `SubOrderDetail` class remove

`ArrayList<SubItemDetail> subItemPart;`

This should fix the issue.

Comment: Sorry it was typo here, I updated code now as advised but still not able to get values of sub elements, Can you think of any other way to loop the sub element of json? Thanks